# Is there a way to loop for the code to open multiple uploaded CSV files using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have this code for my HTML

```
  <input type="file" name="file[]" size="10000" multiple/>
```

And I have this working PHP code for storing the data of the CSV in the database

```
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    $count = 0;

    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $count++;

        $data1 = $emapData[0];
        $temp_2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $emapData[1]);
        $data2 = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d');
        $data3 = $emapData[2];
        $data4 = $emapData[3];
        $data5 = $emapData[4];
        $data6 = $emapData[5];
        $data7 = $emapData[6];
        $data8 = $emapData[7];
```

How can I loop this PHP code to read multiple uploaded CSV files?

Comment: Well, as you say yourself you can implement a loop that iterates over the uploaded files and executes your lines of code for each iteration. What is the question here?

Comment: My code only works for one uploaded csv file. When I upload 2 or more, I always got an error. I think there are some missing codes which are the loops.

Comment: And would you mind telling us _what_ error you get? Since the code you posted does not show anything like a look iterating over the uploaded files we can't follow you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload multiple csvs then, $filename should be an array of file names

```
  $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

You only need to run a loop across $filename and execute the same working code.

```
foreach(  $filename as $key => $val){
//your working code.
}
```

Comment: I already enclosed my working code with yours but I still get errors.
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in...

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Comment: Can you please print the $filename and check if its a proper array? If yes, Can you also check the exact path which is being use din the fgetcsv() ? This should make things clear :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']) && !empty($_FILES['files'])) {
        $no_files = count($_FILES["files"]['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $no_files; $i++) {
            //Your code, Whatever you want to do
            //Access your file by calling this $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i]     
        }
```